# Can't import Web3. swift in Xcode project

Tags: web3swift

Hey I was able to instal the web3swift pod using pod install but afterwards I can't import it in the project, so I can't start using it. Any tips?

Here is the Podfile code

```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Hello' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
pod 'web3swift', '~> 0.8.0'
  # Pods for Hello
  target 'HelloTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'HelloUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[Here is what my Xcode looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBHOL.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, not as a link to a picture of it.

Comment: I have added, do I need to add something else ?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it myself, deleted everything, started from scratch. Then I have build the project and somehow everything works now..